# Internet Explorer has disappeared from my Start Menu on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, start-menu

Internet Explorer has disappeared from my Start Menu.  I know it's still "somewhere" because some apps still manage to launch it.

However, I have been unable to find an .exe file in order to do a shortcut.  Is there a way to re-add it to the start menu?

(I have tried unistalling and reinstalling, but it didn't work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **could** make a shortcut from `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`, however if you're referring to the default **Internet** shortcut at the top of the default start menu ( **not the classic start menu** ), there is an easier way to restore that.

By **default start menu** I mean this one (disregard the classic theme):

[image]

As you can see, there is the default browser and default email client at the top. Internet Explorer will be in place of Firefox for you.

- Right click the taskbar and select **Properties**
- Go to the **Start Menu** tab and click **Customize** (for the regular start menu, not classic)
- At the bottom under **show on start menu** check the **internet** checkbox and select **Internet Explorer** as the browser:

[image]

- Hit OK on each window.

Answer (score 1):

The Internet Explorer executable is called iexplore.exe.

Mine is in C:\$PROGRAM_FILES\Internet Explorer, having upgraded to IE8 in XP.

Comment: For some strange reason on my C drive it's under C:\WINDOWS\ServicePackFiles\i386 .