# Pinned and recent programs disappeared from start menu

Tags: windows-xp, shortcuts, start-menu

I tried to help out my father, but was unable to fix this: For his account the start menu pinned and recent programs disappeared. Programs can only be started by links on the Desktop or by going via "All Programs".

The answer from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/87216/internet-explorer-has-disappeared-from-my-start-menu-on-windows-xp) does not help in any way: Putting Firefox and Thunderbird into the "Show on start menu" panel has no effect. Funny enough, when going there again, both checkboxes are unchecked again. wTF?!

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you:

- Hit Start
- In the blue area to the left of **Log Off** and **Shut down**, right click and select **Properites**
- Next to **Start Menu**, click on the **Customize** button
- There's an option **Number of Programs on Start Menu**

Can you set that to something like 5 or 6.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

1. Go to Start/Run (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)
2. Type `regsvr32 /i shell32.dll`
3. Hit OK
4. Restart your computer

Comment: Just cause its usually a bad idea to run random commands without knowing what they do - http://superuser.com/questions/414472/what-does-regsvr32-i-shell32-dll-do this question and its answers are worth reading. This is a legitimate answer, but more details would be nice :)